# Flash Builder + Eclipse: disable mouse hover popup?

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

Is there any way to disable the inane popup which appears when the mouse hovers over code?

[image: inane popup]

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible… I've filed a bug here: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-29886

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can remove this by going to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers and deselecting everything there. I could not find the same in Flash Builder though you can disable some sort of hover through the same method (Window->Preferences->Flash Builder->Editors->Actionscript Code)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. The ActionScript editor preferences only let me turn off the text that's inside the popups (ie, changing them from being *usually* useless to *always* useless).

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, the eclipse one does work though, I was not able to find anything in Flash Builder that mirrored the eclipse solution exactly though, it may not be possible or I just was unable to figure it out/

Comment: You could always use the Flash Builder plugin for eclipse and turn it off in eclipse? That could work if Flash Builder itself is unable to do so and you really wanted it gone

Comment: How would I “turn it off in Eclise”? I don't know much about Eclipse, so I'm not even sure where I'd start looking.

Comment: If you look at the start of my answer "going to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers" and I have found that Flash Builder is very similar to Eclipse, if you haven't used it before it should seem quite familiar to you

Comment: You can download the trial plugin from the adobe site, the same way you would download Flash Builder but instead select Eclipse-Plugin https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder and follow the step by step installation instructions when it is completed to add to an existing eclipse installation. The newest version of Eclipse can be downloaded here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1 if you do not already have it