# Flash Builder - Disable highlighting of all instances of a word in code editor?

Tags: eclipse, flash, flash-builder

In Flash Builder, for objects, properties, variables and such where your cursor is on it, the editor highlights all instances of that name in the code with a grey box.  This can be very distracting and I was wondering if there was a way to turn it off or if there is a hot key to disable it.

Another things that is very distracting are the mouse hover popups, although apparently there's no way to disable those :

[Flash Builder + Eclipse: disable mouse hover popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891431/flash-builder-eclipse-disable-mouse-hover-popup)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been annoyed by this as well, and finally found something that helps.  You need to turn off "Mark Occurrences" by clicking the button in the IDE that looks like a highlighter.

Here is a link to where I found that answer:

http://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/flex-builder-3-annoyance-code-highlighting-how-do-you-turn-this-thing-off/

Comment: Turning that thing off is the gift that keeps on giving.